# How can I filter Flows in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: filter, enterprise-architect

i am working with EA for a short while now. I know i can filter Elements on a Diagram using the Diagram Filter. I can do that with

```
Right-click diagram background | Context Filtering
```

However this only filters elements/Boxes. How can i filter Information flows?  I have edited the "Note" Fields for all my connections. How can i select only those information flows that contain a Keyword?

Comment: you need connector filter similar like context filter ..?

Comment: yes, just for relations

Comment: The EA function you describe is called Context Filter, not Diagram Filter. The latter is the name of a different function as described in my answer, so please consider correcting the text in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter connectors in diagrams, but not using the Context Filter button which, as Geert notes, only applies to elements. (And **please** don't call them boxes.)

The tool is called Diagram Filters, and is found in the Diagram menu (in EA 11.1). Open that, create a new filter and select Connector in the Search On drop-down list, then specify your filter criteria (eg connector type and name).

In the Diagram Filters window, you can then select which filters to apply at any given moment. These filters are not stored with the diagram; if you want to hide certain connectors in one diagram (semi-) permanently, the Diagram -- Visible Relations dialog Geert mentions allows you to select which connectors to show and hide, and that information is stored with the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

You can only manually hide/show relations on a diagram using the Menu option `Diagram|Visible Relations` or `CTRL-Shift-I`

There is no such thing as a filter for relations.